# use another ssh key in ansible

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, ansible

Ok, so here is my problem :

- I'm on a machine A
- I use my ssh key to connect to a machine B
- I want to use Ansible with my ssh key to connect to machine C and D

And I want ansible to always use the ssh key of the person who is connecting to machine B

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you connecting to C and D _through_ B?

Answer (score 0):

Well,

Well Ansible is simple if you take ansible out of the equation. And think ssh 
1- You can create an account for each person and they can deploy their private key and ansible will use that.
2- I read somewhere that ansible will be able to use forward agent at somepoint mabye it all ready in 1.6 
3- you can wrap ansible with a shell script that will select based on UID or other parameters